# Unable to log in with different account - Azure DevOps connector to Power Automate

Tags: azure-devops, devops, power-automate

I am trying to create a new flow using Azure DevOps connector in Power Automate. I have different accounts, so I am logged in with account A but I want to use my B account with DevOps connector. Apparently, it should be easily done, using “change account”, but as much as I tried, the logging in is always done with my A account instead of the B one.
What I’ve tried:

1. Deleted all my browser history and account passwords.
2. Private Navigation
3. Different navigators (I usually use Chrome, but I tried Edge and Mozzila also)
4. Create new Chrome profile
5. With my B account, log in Power Automate abs create the DevOps connector. Rare enough, the DevOps connector was logged with my A account instead.

Maybe I am missing something which is making me log in  with the account I don’t want.

This shouldn’t be that hard, I can perfectly change accounts with Outlook connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps: login Power Automate via the account B->connector->select azure devops connector->click the button “…”->select option +Add new connection

Result: It will add the new connection via the account B.

[image]

**Update1**

Login Power Automate via the account A->Create azure devops connector->Open it and select the owner tab->click the button Edit->add account B as owner.

[image]

Login Power Automate via the account B( Use incognito mode browser or another browser)->click the option My flows->Team flows(we should see the azure devops connector)->open it and click the button to add new connection.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is not working. I have logged in with my B account but when I try to add a new connection, it doesn’t get the B DevOps account but the A all the time, and I have deleted mi A account password in the browser. I said it was something I have just tried and I tried again, still nothing. 
Have you been able to add a new connection to other account with DevOps connector? 
I’ve been able to do it with other connectors but not using the DevOps one. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi, still nothing. I have tried using a different browser I have never used. I am checking my account. If the issue persists I'll unify my accounts. 
Just out of curiosity, you could log in with two accounts in devOps connector?

Comment: Hi DR17, please check the update1, I can log in with two accounts in DevOps connector and create two connections.

Comment: Hi, I could finally change my account, only when I had started the template in the devOps item. 
Still not knowing why I cannot add the connection from the connections section in the toolbar.
I was logged with my B account instead of A and in the very begining I used the A account in the devOps connector. Once I edited the template, I could change the account easily as you have shown. 
Thanks for all your feedback